# Can AMIs be combined?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, amazon-ami

Is it possible to combine AMIs? If yes, what are the ways to do so?
Working with DL on Cloud and want to know if the above scenario is possible.

Comment: No. What is the _real_ problem that you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

No.

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a copy of a disk that was attached to an Amazon EC2 instance. AMIs cannot be edited.

You could launch an EC2 instance from an AMI, make changes and then create a new AMI.